# NuGet package update removes unchanged files

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I created a nuget package (let's name it Web.Content) with lots of js, css and other content for my other package (named Web). In nuspec file I had file section

```
<file src="Content\**\*.*" target="content\Content" />
```

I made changes in some files from Content folder, then I created a new version of Web.Content package.

I have a project that includes Web and Web.Content packages. After a new version of Web.Content package was created I updated it in my project via nuget. When I try to commit changes of my project, SVN suggests me to commit all content of Web.Comment package.
As I understand, when nuget package was updated all target folder "content\Content" was deleted and copied from package again.
But I need SVN to trace only changes that were made in a couple of files, I don't want to see thousands of changed files because actually changes were made only in some of them.

How can I make nuget copy only changed files? Should I change my nuspec file or should I create some PS script for my package that will override delete'n'copy nuget package update behaviour?

It will be great to have some examples or links.

Tried with NuGet 2.6.40627.9000 and Tortoise SVN 1.7.7.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand NuGet copies files during package installation using somу VS API. This API makes SVN think that the file was deleted and a new file was added(probably this happened because VisualSVN or AnkhSVN is installed).
So we decided to do the next steps:

1. Place our content items in our own folder which name differs from
   "Content"(let's name it "fs_content") because the presence of such
   folder in package triggers NuGet usual installation behavior, but
   we don't need NuGet to install our content in usual way.
2. Write own install.ps1 script that copies our content files to
   destination and put it into Tools package folder.

But after installing such package our content items did not appear where they should appear. My colleague googled some information in NuGet help - "The package must have files in the content or lib folder for Install.ps1 to run. Just having something in the tools folder will not kick this off." We placed a dummy file into "Content" folder and Install.ps1 script began to copy our content from "fs_content" folder as we want.

Now SVN determines only changes made in some files correctly.